# Is there any alternative short name for controller

Tags: model-view-controller, naming-conventions

Is there any alternative short name for controller, I feel this very general word is a little long for typing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think people sometimes use `Ctrl` as a short hand for control, but this is often in the context of Controls like buttons and check boxes.

In MFC (and wxWidgets), they tend to call the Controller class the `App`, e.g. as in `GraphicApp`.